# Use of undeclared type 'HomeViewController'

Tags: ios, swift

Function moveToHome gives error when stating the viewcontroller class. Use of undeclared type 'HomeViewController'. I set the class of the view controller to HomeViewController but it is not being recognized.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase
import SwiftKeychainWrapper
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestore

class SignUpEmail: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Email: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Password: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Firstname: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Lastname: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var City: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Street: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Gender: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var SignupButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var errorLAbel: UILabel!




    var userUid: String!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        SignupButton.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        errorLAbel.alpha = 0


}
   // Check fields, If everything is correct returns Nil otherwise returns error.
    func validateFields() -> String? {
        if Email.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" ||
            Password.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" ||
            Firstname.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" ||
            Lastname.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" ||
            City.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" ||
            Street.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" ||
            Gender.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == "" {

            return "Please fill in all fields."
        }
        // Check if password is secure
        let cleanedPassword = Password.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

            if Utilities.isPasswordValid(cleanedPassword) == false {
                // Password isn't secure enough
                return "Please make sure your password is at least 8 characters, contains a special character and a number."
        }
        return nil
    }

    @IBAction func SignupTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        //Validate
        let error = validateFields()

        if error != nil {
            // Something is wrong with the fields

            showError(error!)
        }
        else {
              // Create User
            // Create clean versions of data
            let lastname = Lastname.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
            let firstname = Firstname.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
            let email = Email.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
            let password = Password.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
            let city = City.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
            let street = Street.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
            let gender = Gender.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, err) in
                //check for errors
                if err != nil {
                    // There was an error creating the user
                    self.showError("Error Creating User")
                }
                else {
                    //User was creating successfully now store
                    let db = Firestore.firestore()

                    db.collection("users").addDocument(data: ["firstname":firstname, "lastname":lastname, "City": city, "Street": street, "Gender":gender, "uid": result!.user.uid]) { (Error) in

                        if error != nil {
                        self.showError("Error saving user data")

                                       }
                }
                // Move to homescreen
                    self.moveToHome()

            }
        }




}
}
    func showError(_ message:String) {

           errorLAbel.text = message
           errorLAbel.alpha = 1
    }
        func moveToHome() {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main.storyboard", bundle: nil)
        let homeViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "HomeVC") as? HomeViewController  //This part gives error

        view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
        view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

}
```

(Ignore had to add extra text to be able to post)

Comment: Have you created a UIViewController class named "HomeViewController.swift" ? Is there a "HomeViewController.swift" file in the left side bar in your Xcode?

Comment: You shouldn't ignore the warning to add extra text, because it correctly detected that it is not possible to find your issue with this little information. Please add more relevant info.

Comment: It is most probably because Target Membership  is not added  for the file "HomeViewController.swift". If that is the case what you have to do is, select the file "HomeViewController.swift" in left side panel. Then go to File inspector in right side panel and check for Target Membership. If the tick corresponding to your project is not enabled, then that is the issue. you just have to enable it.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
```

uses "Main" instead of "Main.storyboard"

and make sure that the StoryboadID has been set
[image]